# Apache SetEnvIf / CustomLog log filtering not working

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm having a hard time trying to exclude lines from Apache access log.

I'm on Apache Windows 2.4.25 64 bit

I tried:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*" dontlog
LogFormat  "%{%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S}t [%h %{tid}P] %>s \"%r\" (%bb/%Dmis)" common
CustomLog "${LOGROOT}/ApacheAccess.log" common env=!dontlog
```

Which works fine - nothing gets logged in access.log

However if I try the same with:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*Check.*" dontlog
```

It seems to be ignored, ie I get lines like:

> 29/11/19 13:43:51 [127.0.0.1 15896] 200 "GET /zerofp/server?Check HTTP/1.1" (17b/177042mis)

What am I missing ? How to correctly filter lines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok The reason this is not working is because `Request_URI` does not include the query string so the regexp never match.

Here is how to do this:

```
# Set the "dontlog" environment variable when the query string matches one of multiple patters to filter out access.log

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ".*?Check.*" [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ".*someothercond*" 
RewriteRule .* - [E=dontlog:yes] 

LogFormat  "%{%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S}t %r" common
CustomLog "${LOGROOT}/ApacheAccess.log" common env=!dontlog
```

Comment: You  can also use `QUERY_STRING`.